# Will the comparison of two float numbers consume more CPU time than two ints?

Tags: cpu

Will the comparison of two float numbers consume more CPU time than two ints?

Comment: Generally speaking, no. They are stored in way where comparison is simple. Also, many CPU have hardware optimizations for floating point numbers. Can you provide more details? Unless you're doing real-time, this shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With today's CPUs (excluding maybe embedded machines and the Atom) you can't really make predictions on how fast a single inctruction in code may be.

First of all, it may be removed by the compiler if it's known to be irrelevant, it may be rewritten by the compiler into something different which is known to be faster, etc. That's one pitfall.

Secondly, CPUs can execute more than one instruction per cycle, or make them asynchronously and do other things while waiting for the FPU, etc.

In your specific case, comparing two numbers should be instant, i. e. in one cycle. But you probably can't use that result in that very same cycle already. But this should hold true for both integers and floating-point numbers.

Remember that it's just a series of bits and while floating-point numbers may be a little different due to their structure, it's still a pretty easy problem (compare sign, compare exponent, compare mantissa).

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, standard IEEE 754 floating point numbers are stored in such a way that if you treat them as integers, they compare the same way:

| sign | exponent | significand |

The significand (a word I had completely forgotten before consulting the Wikipedia article) is the first few significant digits of the number.

If two floating point numbers `a < b`, then you have one of:

- `a` negative, `b` not negative;
- both same sign, but `a`'s exponent < `b`'s exponent; or
- both same sign and exponent, but `a` < `b`.

So you can simply take the 32 bits of each number as integers, and compare them using normal integer arithmetic.  I do not know if this is what compilers do in practice.  There are a few special representations for certain numbers and these edge cases may mean the FP processor has to do it differently.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation

Comment: You can compare floating-point numbers as integers so long as one or both is positive; if both are negative the comparison won't work properly.

Answer (score -1):

processing a float even if treated as integer will take more because a float is bigger, on php i tested once just dividing 1 for 3 to 32.000.000 decimal digits and i took about 0.33 seconds, dividing 1 for 3 to 10 decimal digits took 0.0002 or something like that (these values may be a little off but depending on the size of the float it can take you a lot and to work with such big floats will take a hell of a lot of time, if you want to be more specific and test this subject it would be ideal because part of the time i waited could be because of memory speed or something like that, and not cpu)

anyway considering that you won't be crazy enough to work with floats with more that 50 decimal places you should be fine

Comment: I dont know aboyt your plattform, but here both are 32 bits. PHP really is not a good measure when thinking about low-level performance.

Comment: @Michael Nett i know but maybe you can do the same test on a low level language, i guess your result will be pretty much the same because moving large numbers even if floats are interpreted as integers will also take longer and do operations with them too. besides that all high level languages have to be compiled to low level in order to run, if the difference i spotted was not big then knowing there are huge differences between between low level and high level languages it would be comprehensible, but the difference was monstrous. my pc is x64 and i'm using xampp (x86) with win7 x64 ultimate